# How to turn off my Twitter or mark all messages as private for 90 days?

Tags: twitter

When hunting for a job, I don't want the hiring manager, director, SVP (who does a final approval of my offer) to make shallow judgment on me because of my tweets.

I know how to make all posts on Facebook private for all public viewers, so only friends can see my posts.

How do I do that for Twitter:

1. Either make all tweets private for 90 days, or
2. Make my account private or disappear for 90 days

Comment: @BlindSpots you are saying I can change all tweets to protected and then after the job hunting, change them all back to public?

Comment: Please review that Twitter article:  *[About public and protected Tweets](https://help.twitter.com/en/safety-and-security/public-and-protected-Tweets)*.  Pay particular attention to the section about needing to block  ["accounts that began following you before you protected your Tweets"](https://help.twitter.com/en/safety-and-security/public-and-protected-tweets#:~:text=Accounts%20that%20began%20following%20you%20before%20you%20protected%20your%20Tweets)" is you want your Tweets to be hidden from those accounts as well.

Comment: @BlindSpots actually, I would rather not protect it, because when people search, they will see my photo, name, and it will say below "These Tweets are protected"... it adds a huge amount of secrecy to the reader: why is this person not allowing other people to see what he says? I would rather the account appears to not exist instead (deactivate it for 30 days)